# make NSTextField in NSTableCellView firstResponder()

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, nstextfield

**for those not into reading 20 comments to look for the answer. here is what worked for me:**

1. the tableView is View Based, not Cell Based (attributes inspector)
2. tableView.reloadData() wasn’t fast enough. using insertRow(at[0]:withAnimation:.leftSlide) instead worked fine
3. make sure that the NSTextField as well as the NSTextFieldCell are editable (attributes inspector)

the final code:

```
tableViewAlarms.insertRows(at: [0], withAnimation: .effectFade)

let keyView = tableViewAlarms.view(atColumn: 0, row: 0, makeIfNecessary: false) as! NSTableCellView

self.view.window!.makeFirstResponder(keyView.textField)
```

**the question:**

got one question. I have been stuck for some time making my NSTableView work the way I want it to. I'm a beginner and working with classes, inheritance, and views is giving me a lot of trouble.

[screenshot, the NSTextField is activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si3mm.png)

you add a row to the NSTableView by pushing the '+' button.

the NSTextField in the first tableColumn is editable and begins editing when double-clicked

now I want the NSTextField in the first column to be activated automatically (show cursor, responding to text input via keyboard) when a row is added.

so far i have tried:

```
class NSTextFieldSubClass: NSTextField {

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

I also played around with the bindings of the cell (or the NSTextField itself to be precise), but since I don't really know my way around those it went nowhere

what I think is the way to go:

make the NSTextField the firstResponder when the cell is created, but I don't know how. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

also: how exactly is the state of an NSTextField called when the cursor is blinking?

edit:

as for the subclass, this is all I tried:

```
class NSTextFieldSubClass: NSTextField {

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

edit screenshot:

[image: these are the connections]

edit2:

[image: edit2: attributes inspector tableView]

edit3:

[image: edit3: bindings NSTextField]

edit4:

[image: edit4: error]

Comment: anyone? would help a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't subclass `NSTextField`. You can make the text field in a view based table view first responder right out of the box.

It's pretty easy.

Assuming you know `row` and `column` (in your example row 0 and column 0) get the table cell view with `view(atColumn: 0, row` and make the text field first responder.

```
let keyView = tableView.view(atColumn: 0, row: 0, makeIfNecessary: false) as! NSTableCellView
view.window!.makeFirstResponder(keyView.textField)
```

And what is the second outlet for? Just use the standard default `textField`.

Comment: Isn't this the same as my answer?

Comment: Basically yes, but all the optional bindings are not needed. The code must not crash otherwise you made a design mistake. Further the explicit selection and the dispatch block is not needed either. A text field in a table view accepts first responder by default. As the enclosing object is a window controller you get the window from its `view`

Comment: thank you for responding. so i understand and added your code to the '+' button function right after tableView.reloadData(). now it throws me "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" which ich do not understand at all. sorry for not letting go haha

Comment: Are we talking about a **view based** table view?

Comment: the tableView.view(...) is nil

Comment: i read about it several times, honestly i cant tell you since i still dont fully understand the difference. i think its cell based since i just use the NSTableView Xcode offers, didnt change anything like creating custom cell or nib files (i only know half of what im talking about here)

Comment: My answer works only for view based table views. Please select Interface Builder, then select the table view (not the enclosing scroll view) and  press ⌥⌘4. The `Content Mode` at the top indicates the mode. You are strongly encouraged to use only view based table views. They are so much easier to handle.

Comment: oh so hats how you find out. it is view based though. ill add a screenshot to my post if that helps. thanks

Comment: Then my code is supposed to work unless you messed up the view. I recommend to delete the table cell view and drag a new one onto column 0.

Comment: tried it. still not working. wow this is annoying. could it have aything to do with the bindings or the way they are set? another screenshot ⬆️

Comment: Not working means it does nothing or it crashes? Is the table view outlet connected?

Comment: crashes, same error. view is nil. is there any info i could provide? thanks for your effort so far!!!
tableView outlets are connected to datasource and delegate. referencing outlet is connected to ViewController. the tableview works fine

Comment: Is it `nil` or is it not `NSTableViewCell`? Has the row already been inserted?

Comment: nil. screenshot ⬆️ has the row allready been inserted? -> it crashes before the row is visible. okay thats kind of an obvious problem. it worked before with @Willeke answer so i didnt pay attention to it.

any easy (i.e. short) way to wait for the reloadData() to finish before yur code is executed?

Comment: Don't use `reloadData` use `insertRows(at:withAnimation:` before calling `tableView.view(atColumn:row:` As a bonus you could get a smart animation for free.

Comment: enjoyed that .slideleft. thanks for that hehe. this is the code now. no crashes. the row is added, but the textfield doesnt do anything.
   `tableViewAlarms.insertRows(at: [0], withAnimation: .slideLeft)`
     `let keyView1 = self.tableViewAlarms.view(atColumn: 0, row: 0, makeIfNecessary: false)`
            
       `let keyView2 = keyView1 as! NSTableCellView`
        
        `self.view.window!.makeFirstResponder(keyView2.textField)` also the view is not nil anymore. it is an NSTableCellView

Comment: Is the text field marked as editable? Select the text field in the table view cell in Interface Builder, press ⌥⌘4. In the `Behaviour` popup select `Editable`. Another hint. You might add the line `self.tableViewAlarms.scrollRowToVisible(0)` before `let keyView1 = self.tableViewAlarms.view(atColumn:row:...)`. If the row is not visible the code will crash

Comment: wow i was aware of that. so i always made sure the NSTextField is editable. never checked if the NSTextFieldCell is editable. holy s**t, thank you so so much haha. too bad i allready spent hours coding a different path because nothing worked. still very happy i figured it out and that there its no that much magic involved...

Answer (score 3):

At the end of the action method of the '+' button, after adding the row do:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    // get the cell view
    let view = self.tableView.view(atColumn: 0, row: row, makeIfNecessary: false)
    if let cellView = view as? NSTableCellView {
        // get the text field
        if let textField = cellView.textField {
            // make the text field first responder
            if textField.acceptsFirstResponder {
                self.tableView.selectRowIndexes(IndexSet(integer:row), byExtendingSelection: false)
                self.tableView.window?.makeFirstResponder(textField)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: thank you, i understand mostly. whats the window though? xcode also shows the error "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'window'"

Comment: `window` is the window where the table view is.

Comment: thank you. it gives the textfield of the cell of the added row a blue outline (as is when you put in text) but the cursor is missing. the cursor appears after one (not two) clicks. any idea?

Comment: No, I've no idea. How do you add or insert the row?

Comment: by adding an obejct to the datasource array and then reloading the tableview. the reload function sits right before the code you wrote for me. i tried to put it behind it as well, that doesnt change anything to my surprise

Comment: i oversaw the code you added to the answer. what it does is it marks the whole row. so now the row is colored and the first cell is outlined. getting closer haha.

also this shows up in the console: 2018-03-20 04:39:06.502922+0100 chartalarm[776:13293] Failed to connect (alarmPriceTextField) outlet from (NSTableCellView) to (chartalarm.NSTextFieldSubClass): missing setter or instance variable

Comment: Which class has a `alarmPriceTextField` outlet? Does `chartalarm.NSTextFieldSubClass` do anything with the first responder status?

Comment: If you override `becomeFirstResponder` and do nothing then the text field won't become first resonpder.